# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:

Tags: python, file-io, ioerror

I keep getting the following error.

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Viral Patel\\Documents\\GitHub\\3DPhotovoltaics\\Data_Output\\Simulation_Data\\Raw_Data\\Raw_Simulation_Data_2014-03-24 17:21:20.545000.csv'
```

I think it is due to the timestamp at the end of the filename. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot use `:` in Windows filenames, see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ; it is one of the reserved characters:

> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - `<` (less than)
>   - `>` (greater than)
>   - `:` (colon)
>   - `"` (double quote)
>   - `/` (forward slash)
>   - `\` (backslash)
>   - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - `?` (question mark)
>   - `*` (asterisk)

Use a different character not on the reserved character list.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the colons to dashes and it worked

Comment: @user3369317 According to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), `20140324T172120,545000` would be fine as well.

Comment: In my case I the code added 2 backslashes making the script think it is part of the filename, and not of the path.