# python [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: u'Escuela Sab\xe1tica Part 2.doc'

Tags: python, unicode

I've seen many similar questions, but none that fix my problem. I'm trying to open a file with a unicode filename, but get the error:

[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: u'Escuela Sab\xe1tica Part 2.doc'

I've tried using open, codecs.open, and io.open to open the file (which I didn't think would matter for a binary file, but whatever). No dice. I think the clue might be the filename:

u'Escuela Sab\xe1tica Part 2.doc'

When printed, this file name works fine:

Escuela Sabática Part 2.doc

But I think it's weird the error prints it as u'...\xe1...' instead of u'...\uxxx...'. I'm still not comfortable with unicode, so that's my suspicion. I've tried encoding and decoding the filename ('utf-8') before opening with no success.

Edit: Version is python 2.7.3. Code snippet:

```
with open(to_path, "wb") as to_file:
    to_file.write(f.read())
```

The error traces back to the 'with open' line, and the code works for files without unicode in the file name.

Comment: What version of Python is that? And you should post the snippet of code you're running which raises that error.

Comment: You should _always_ mention the Python version with Unicode questions (preferably using the appropriate tag), since Unicode handling in Python 3 is rather different to Python 2. And for this question it would also be good to know the OS & the filesystem. FWIW, the Windows NTFS filesystem uses UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: Version and code snippet added above.

Comment: According to the Python 2.7 [Unicode filenames docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames) this shouldn't be happening, assuming that `to_path` is a valid Unicode string object. But I guess it's worth trying to explicitly encode it. What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` return?

Comment: what happens if you use some unique Unicode name (to exclude the possibility that some other program has already opened the file)?

Comment: Make sure, you use raw-string literals if you use a literal backslash inside the path. Related: [IOError: [Errno 22\] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22620965/4279)

Comment: sys.getfilesystemencoding() returns 'UTF-8'. Also, this filename is a string I am given from the server I am downloading the file from. I just tried writing a file with this name manually as suggested below, and it worked. But I still can't get it to work in the program.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on Python 2.7.10:

```
with open(u'Escuela Sab\xe1tica Part 2.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('test')

>>> ls Esc*
```

Escuela Sabática Part 2.doc (I'm using text instead of code sample to show the accent).

```
>>> cat Esc*
test
```

Perhaps you are reading instead of writing?