# save videos to file system from request.FILES.getlist()

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

In my project at first was necessary to save in my file systems the images from  `request.FILES.getlist()` and I can do that with `PIL` like this:

```
if request.FILES:
    imgs = request.FILES.getlist('file')

    dir = '\\some\\directory\\'

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dir)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dir))
        for f in imgs:
            i = Image.open(f)
            i.save(dir+str(f))
    else:
        for f in imgs:
            i = Image.open(f)
            i.save(direc+str(f))

else:
    imgs = None
```

That works fine but now I need to store videos and images from `request.FILES.getlist()` **How can I store both types?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Thanks to Naffes I can solve this just to be specific the code is:**

```
if request.FILES:
    imgs = request.FILES.getlist('file')

    dir = '\\some\\directory\\'
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dir)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dir))
    for f in imgs:
        with open(dir + str(f), 'wb') as dest:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                dest.write(chunk)

else:
    imgs = None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to write your uploaded files to disk

```
if request.FILES:
    imgs = request.FILES.getlist('file')

    dir = '\\some\\directory\\'
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dir)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dir))
    for f in imgs:
        with open(dir + '<filename>', 'wb') as dest:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                dest.write(chunk)
```

You don't even need to use `PIL`

Comment: It gives me this error: `Exception Value: 
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: u'\\some\\directory\\<filename>'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620965/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-wb-or-filename

Comment: Hi Nafees, the error was for `<filename>` so i use just `filename` and store a file with that name `\some\directory\filename` then I try using just `(direc + f, 'wb')` and gives me this error `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, TemporaryUploadedFile found`

Comment: I got it just conert to string like this  `with open(direc + str(f), 'wb') as dest:`